# How to calculate the probability from frequencies

Tags: r

I have stored the month as:

```
count.data <- count.month

x    freq
Jan   7
Feb   23
Mar   86
Apr   281
```

now I want to find the probability of X.

Example:

probability of Jan attribute: 7 / (7+23+86+281)  #total freq

Comment: Could you please expand your question? Honestly, it is not clear and I think I am not the only one who think that. Thank you.

Comment: @SabDeM Is it ok now?

Comment: I don't get it.. Why this question is on hold? The question is quite clear with the help of example. I don't think that the person who are answering are not understanding the problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this. Assuming your dat.frame is named `dat`:

```
dat$prob <- dat$freq/sum(dat$freq)
dat
#x freq       prob
#1 Jan    7 0.01763224
#2 Feb   23 0.05793451
#3 Mar   86 0.21662469
#4 Apr  281 0.70780856
```

Comment: what if I want to access the probability of Feb? Can you please tell how can I do that ?

Comment: `dat[2,]` will select the second row. Is this what you mean?

Comment: yeah.. something like that.. But instead of writing dat[2,] , can't I use names like jan, feb.... ? can u give me example for that. Using numeric values are confusing while having a large dataset..

Comment: Something like calling the Feb probability in a variable

Comment: With `dplyr` you can do something like this: `library(dplyr);dat %>% filter(x=="Feb")`

Answer (score 3):

or with `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% mutate(prob = freq / sum(freq))
    x freq       prob
1 Jan    7 0.01763224
2 Feb   23 0.05793451
3 Mar   86 0.21662469
4 Apr  281 0.70780856
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df$prob <- prop.table(df$freq)
df
```

Output:

```
    x freq       prob
1 Jan    7 0.01763224
2 Feb   23 0.05793451
3 Mar   86 0.21662469
4 Apr  281 0.70780856
```

If you want to access a specific month:

```
 prop.table(df$freq)[df$x == "Feb"] 
[1] 0.05793451
```

`sqldf` package:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT x, freq, (freq*1.0)/(SELECT SUM(freq) FROM df) AS prob
      FROM df')
```

Comment: I always forget about (the very useful) `prop.table`!

Comment: @SabDeM Yes, it is a very concise way to get the proportions. I was lucky to remember it!

Comment: @Flames I added in my answer an option to access a specific month as you asked

Answer (score 2):

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, prob:= freq/sum(freq)]
```