# How to calculate various probabilities from the counts per person

Tags: r, conditional-statements, sequence, probability, prop

I have a dataframe `df` which contains per user responses as below:

```
userID pred_task obs1_task obs2_task exp1_task exp2_task postPOE_task

3108       H        E        E        E         M           M
3207       H        H        E        NA        H           M
3350       M        H        H        NA        H           H
3961       E        E        E        E         E           M
4021       H        H        E        M         H           E
```

With some pre-processing I have been able to have additional features which contain the counts of:

`E` = Number of times *E* was reported by a participant,

`M` = Number of times *M* was reported by a participant,

`H` = Number of times *H* was reported by a participant,

Moreover, I have also counted the bigram transitions (the counts of two consecutive sequences) where:

`EE` --> Transition from *E* to *E*,

`EM` --> Transition from *E* to *M*,

`EH` --> Transition from *E* to *H*,

`ME` --> Transition from *M* to *E*,

`MM` --> Transition from *M* to *M*,

`MH` --> Transition from *M* to *H*,

`HE` --> Transition from *H* to *E*,

`HM` --> Transition from *H* to *M*,

`HH` --> Transition from *H* to *H*,

The updated `df` is as below:

```
userID pred_tsk obs1_tsk obs2_tsk exp1_tsk exp2_tsk postPOE_tsk  E   M   H   EE  EM  EH  MM  ME  MH  HH  HE  HM
3108       H        E        E        E         M           M    3   2   1   2   1    0   1   0   0   0   0   0
3207       H        H        E        NA        H           M    1   1   3    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
3350       M        H        H        NA        H           H    0   1   4    0   0   0   0   0   1   2   0   0
3961       E        E        E        E         E           M    5   1   0    4   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4021       H        H        E        M         H           E    2   1   3    0   1   0   0   0   1   1   2   0
```

Please note that:

. Users could report on 6 different tasks.

. `E`, `M` and `H` are the counts of how many times the users reported a task to be `Hard`, `Mixed` or `Easy`. The sum of these counts can (at most) be 6.

. `EE`, `EM`, `EH`, `MM`, `ME`, `MH`, `HH`, `HE`, `HM` are the transitions of reported responses. Such as on one task a user reported `E` and then on the other task they reported `M` so it is the transition `EM`. Conversely, for the other transitions

**Question:**

I am interested in calculating different frequencies *`P(next)`*, *`P(prev)`* and *`P(next|prev)`* for each of the reported states i.e.,

*`P(next_E)`*, *`P(next_M)`*, *`P(next_H)`*

*`P(prev_E)`*, *`P(prev_M)`*, *`P(prev_H)`*

Where the formulas or the description of probabilities is as below:

*`P(next)`* = Proportion of times a state occurred as a next state

*`P(prev)`* = Proportion of times a state occurred as a previous state

*`P(next|prev)`* = count(prev -> next) / 
                      count(prev)

I understand the question is a bit long, I thank you for reading this far and would appreciate any tips on this.

The following post is somewhat related [How to calculate the probability from frequencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647279/how-to-calculate-the-probability-from-frequencies)

**dput(df)**

```
structure(list(userID = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("E","H","M"), class = "factor"), 
pred_task = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c(" E", " H"), class = "factor"),
obs1_task = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c(" E", " H"), class = "factor"),
obs2_task = structure(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c(" E", " M", " NA"), class = "factor"), 
exp1_task = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("E", "H", "M"), class = "factor"),
exp2_task = structure(c(4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "E", "H", "M"), class = "factor"), 
postPOE_task = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "M"), class = "factor"), 
E = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L),
M = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L), 
H = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
EE = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L), 
EM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
EH = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
MM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
ME = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
MH = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L), 
HH = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L), 
HE = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
HM = c(NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("3108", "3207", "3350", "3961", "4021"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will calculate the proportions you need, even with a much larger dataframe. Just be sure that the input dataframe has the exact structure as your example `df`.

Also, I think I found some inconsistencies in your `dput(df)` relative to your updated `df`. I fixed the `dput(df)` to reflect the values in your example `df`.

```
# "fixed" df to reflect example    
structure(list(userID = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("E","H","M"), class = "factor"), 
                 pred_task = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c(" E", " H"), class = "factor"),
                 obs1_task = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c(" E", " H"), class = "factor"),
                 obs2_task = structure(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c(" E", " M", " NA"), class = "factor"), 
                 exp1_task = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("E", "H", "M"), class = "factor"),
                 exp2_task = structure(c(4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "E", "H", "M"), class = "factor"), 
                 postPOE_task = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "M"), class = "factor"), 
                 E = c(3L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 2L),
                 M = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                 H = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 3L), 
                 EE = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L), 
                 EM = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
                 EH = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                 MM = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                 ME = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                 MH = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
                 HH = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L), 
                 HE = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L), 
                 HM = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c("3108", "3207", "3350", "3961", "4021"))
```

The function:

```
transition.probs <- function(df) {
  require(dplyr)
  df.states <- df[, c(11:19)]
  state.factors <- colnames(df.states)
  state.total <- sum(df.states, na.rm = TRUE)
  state.sums <- colSums(df.states, na.rm = TRUE)
  state.df <-data.frame(sums = state.sums, id = as.character(state.factors))
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  state.df[grepl(".E", state.df$id), ] %>%
    .[, 1] %>%
    sum() -> next.E.count
  state.df[grepl("E.", state.df$id), ] %>%
    .[, 1] %>%
    sum() -> prev.E.count
  state.df[grepl(".M", state.df$id), ] %>%
    .[, 1] %>%
    sum() -> next.M.count
  state.df[grepl("M.", state.df$id), ] %>%
    .[, 1] %>%
    sum() -> prev.M.count
  state.df[grepl(".H", state.df$id), ] %>%
    .[, 1] %>%
    sum() -> next.H.count
  state.df[grepl("H.", state.df$id), ] %>%
    .[, 1] %>%
    sum() -> prev.H.count
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  next.E.p <- next.E.count / state.total
  prev.E.p <- prev.E.count / state.total
  next.M.p <- next.M.count / state.total
  prev.M.p <- prev.M.count / state.total
  next.H.p <- next.H.count / state.total
  prev.H.p <- prev.H.count / state.total
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  state.df[grepl("EE", state.df$id), ] %>%
    .[, 1] -> EE.count
  state.df[grepl("EM", state.df$id), ] %>%
    .[, 1] -> EM.count
  state.df[grepl("EH", state.df$id), ] %>%
    .[, 1] -> EH.count
  state.df[grepl("MM", state.df$id), ] %>%
    .[, 1] -> MM.count
  state.df[grepl("ME", state.df$id), ] %>%
    .[, 1] -> ME.count
  state.df[grepl("MH", state.df$id), ] %>%
    .[, 1] -> MH.count
  state.df[grepl("HH", state.df$id), ] %>%
    .[, 1] -> HH.count
  state.df[grepl("HE", state.df$id), ] %>%
    .[, 1] -> HE.count
  state.df[grepl("HM", state.df$id), ] %>%
    .[, 1] -> HM.count
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  EE.E <- EE.count / prev.E.count
  EM.E <- EM.count / prev.E.count
  EH.E <- EH.count / prev.E.count
  MM.M <- MM.count / prev.M.count
  ME.M <- ME.count / prev.M.count
  MH.M <- MH.count / prev.M.count
  HH.H <- HH.count / prev.H.count
  HE.H <- HE.count / prev.H.count
  HM.H <- HM.count / prev.H.count
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  state.summary <- data.frame(trans.state = as.factor(c(
    "next.E",
    "prev.E",
    "next.M",
    "prev.M",
    "next.H",
    "prev.H",
    "EE.E",
    "EM.M",
    "EH.H",
    "MM.M",
    "ME.M",
    "MH.M",
    "HH.H",
    "HE.H",
    "HM.H")),
    p = as.numeric(c(
      next.E.p,
      prev.E.p,
      next.M.p,
      prev.M.p,
      next.H.p,
      prev.H.p,
      EE.E,
      EM.E,
      EH.E,
      MM.M,
      ME.M,
      MH.M,
      HH.H,
      HE.H,
      HM.H)))
  state.summary
}
```

The output dataframe:

```
transition.probs(df)
trans.state        p
1       next.E 0.473684
2       prev.E 0.473684
3       next.M 0.263158
4       prev.M 0.157895
5       next.H 0.315789
6       prev.H 0.421053
7         EE.E 0.666667
8         EM.M 0.333333
9         EH.H 0.000000
10        MM.M 0.333333
11        ME.M 0.000000
12        MH.M 0.666667
13        HH.H 0.500000
14        HE.H 0.375000
15        HM.H 0.125000
```

Comment: Thanks @Tavaro for posting a solution to this.
I actually wanted these sums for each user ID separately.
Could you please suggest a solution for this case?